# rforcecom.getObjectDescription got error towards come salesforce data table

Tags: r, salesforce

I used this function to get all the fields name of Campaign table, but it returned this error
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [**salesforcer**](https://github.com/StevenMMortimer/salesforcer) package can return details about object metadata in Salesforce. Here is an example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(salesforcer)
sf_auth(username, password, security_token)

# retrieve a list of metadata about the Contact object
contact_object <- sf_describe_object('Contact')
#> $activateable
#> [1] "false"
#> 
#> $childRelationships
#> [1] "..."
#> 
#> $fields
#> [1] "..."

# retrieve a tbl_df of all fields on the Contact object
contact_fields <- sf_describe_object_fields('Contact')
#> # A tibble: 64 x 39
#>   aggregatable aiPredictionField autoNumber  ...
#>   <chr>        <chr>             <chr>     
#> 1 true         false             false     
#> 2 false        false             false     
#> 3 true         false             false
#> #...
```